# Localisation workflow BartyCrouch and microsoft translator API in iOS

Tags: swift, azure, shell, localization

I have a very specific question, was wondering has anyone tried workflow with BartyCrouch script and api.cognitive.microsofttranslator in Swift? I have a mixed project : Storyboards + SwiftUI that i needs to get multiple languages. I guess I am just confused on the first steps.  I have a small test project working with BartyCrouch is it just out of the box translating from Azure?
Any code examples on the web are welcome.

There was some talk of adding Google translate as a feature to the framework, from 2 years ago. Not sure where we are now.
https://github.com/FlineDev/BartyCrouch/issues/160

Comment: @DeepDave-MT did you maybe had a go? these issues seem to be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

So everything worked after setting up the BartyCrouch and Azure in a right way. The steps are here if anyone is looking for.

1. Setting up Azure Translator instance

> - this took a while as I needed the GLOBAL region and to make this work free of charge
>   First set the Subscription and than **Resource** and than connect it to your Subscription via Translator in this case. This will generate secret key that we need for BartyCrouch to connect to the api.
>   With the key and global we can test if translation is working with CURL/Postman

2. Configure the .toml file that you generated when installing BC (I did from Homebrew). Had issue here with a paths to my Localizable.strings file ["./your-app"]. I had to add `translate` to the tasks in .toml file
3. Place **BartyCrouch** script into BuildPhases and run build

> bartycrouch update -x

4. Make sure when adding a new Localizable.string file and new language to have all the translations in `""` empty string

Happy localization to you..

Comment: If you liked BartyCrouch, you might want to also check out its successor: https://remafox.app – it has a GUI and many other improvments over BartyCrouch.